# pandas count number of same element in column and erase if the number is small

Tags: python, count, pandas

I have two questions

first one is about counting and second one is erasing

My data set looks like this

```
X = pd.read_table(dstore, sep=',', warn_bad_lines=True, error_bad_lines=True)
X.sort(['Chain_key'], ascending=[True], inplace=True)


       IRI_KEY  OU    EST_ACV       Market_Name  Open  Clsd  Chain_key
230    229030  GR   6.619999    SEATTLE/TACOMA  1123  9998          1
264    231588  GR   5.286999    SEATTLE/TACOMA   960  9998          1
291    233708  GR   5.556000    SEATTLE/TACOMA   607  9998          1 
1083   288392  GR   5.556000    SEATTLE/TACOMA   902  1400          1
167    223660  GR   5.825996    SEATTLE/TACOMA  1123  9998          1
1128   292476  GR  12.683000       LOS ANGELES  1048  9998          2
451    243939  GR  15.306000  WEST TEX/NEW MEX  1196  9998          2
980    281109  GR  15.800990       PORTLAND,OR   435  9998          2
945    278738  GR   9.685997       LOS ANGELES   435  9998          2
1473   656089  GR  14.738000       PHOENIX, AZ  1192  9998          2
1329   648019  GR  13.397990       PHOENIX, AZ   902  9998          3
999    283190  GR  19.213990        SACRAMENTO  1059  1450          3
207    227169  GR  18.780990  WEST TEX/NEW MEX  1075  9998          3
1026   285252  GR  31.476000  WEST TEX/NEW MEX   659  9998          4
1231   535552  GR  22.150990           SPOKANE  1145  9998          4
455    244163  GR  19.213990       PORTLAND,OR   435  1424          4
328    236100  GR  19.120000  WEST TEX/NEW MEX   493  9998          5
1228   535326  GR  15.429990       PHOENIX, AZ  1190  9998          6
436    242841  GR  20.472990       PORTLAND,OR  1285  9998          6
```

then I want to count number of same element for Chain_key column like this

1: 5
2: 5
3: 3
4: 3
5: 1
...

and

how can I erase the row if their chain_key has small number of same element
for example erase less than 2 then in above case chain_key 5 should be erased
because they have only 1 (5: 1)

I try group by or some other things but didn't catch yet..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for size:

```
In [11]: df.groupby('Chain_key').size()
Out[11]:
Chain_key
1            5
2            5
3            3
4            3
5            1
6            2
dtype: int64
```

To remove rows with fewer than 2 in the group, use filter:

```
In [12]: df.groupby('Chain_key').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 2)
```